# C# streamwriter does not overwrite futher information

Tags: c#, streamwriter

i'm working on a calculator project for my school.

i have a problem with overwriting my operations to a text document, normally i should have this on my text file:

```
1|peter|DESKTOP-P6IL7VV|19/11/2017 11:38:11  ==>  5 x 5=25       
2|peter|DESKTOP-P6IL7VV|19/11/2017 11:38:15  ==>  25 + 3=28      
3|peter|DESKTOP-P6IL7VV|19/11/2017 11:38:27  ==>  28 / 2=14      
4|peter|DESKTOP-P6IL7VV|19/11/2017 11:38:31  ==>  14 + 6=20      
5|peter|DESKTOP-P6IL7VV|19/11/2017 11:38:35  ==>  20 - 20=0                
(example from my teacher)
```

but every time i write something, it deletes the first line, and overwrites only the last operation, i need every time i click on the result button, it overwrites to my file with the order of numbers

here is my coding:

```
private void result_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            result();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            txtIngave.Text = "Error!";
        }
        try
        {
            if (!txtResultaat.Text.Equals(string.Empty) && btnLog.IsChecked 
            == true)
            {
                int i = 1;
                using (StreamWriter myOper = new 
     StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Ach\Documents\Visual Studio 
      2017\Projects\TaakCalculator\log\log.txt"))
                {
                   myOper.WriteLine(i.ToString() + " | " + "Achraf | " + System.Environment.MachineName + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " | ==> " + txtResultaat.Text);
                }
                i++;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Loser");
        }
    }
```

Comment: add **true** at new 
     StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Achraf Alajdi\Documents\Visual Studio 
      2017\Projects\TaakCalculator\log\log.txt",**true**) to append text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the

```
StreamWriter(string path, bool append)
```

constructor with the parameter `append` being `true`.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx):

> *append*
>
> **true** to append data to the file; **false** to overwrite the file. If the specified file does not exist, this parameter has no effect, and the constructor creates a new file.

Comment: ok thanks it's fixed but my int stays at number 1, doesnt change how can i fix it ?

Comment: @ach.ala because you set it to 1 again each time you call the method. Put the declaration outside the method so it doesn't reset it to 1.

Comment: @ach.ala: Of course. You are initializing `i` right before writing to the file to 1 and virtually immediately write to the file. As soon as you leave the block, `i` is *forgotten* and will be set to 1 again before writing to the file. You'll have to declare `i` (think of a better name) as an instance variable of your class in order to maintain the value.

Comment: ok guys 
thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If this answer has helped you, please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: how do i mark it ?

Comment: Below the arrow for up-/downvoting there should be a grey checkmark that turns green when clicking it.

Comment: @Paul Kertscher it's done thanks